# Not able to upload file by using dropbox on cordova app based on meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to use dropbox to upload files on my cordova app based on meteor i.e., user will be given option if he wants to upload file using dropbox if user click on the button then inappbrowser should open from where user will be authenticated and can upload file.

I am using below script

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="id_dropbox" data-app-key="xxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

This is the code

```
      e.preventDefault();
         Dropbox.choose({
            linkType: "direct",
            multiselect: false,
            extensions: ['.doc'],
            success: function(files) {
                console.log("files ", files[0]);
                if(files[0]['bytes']<1000000){
                    GetBlobDataDropbox(files) //function to upload file
                }else{
                   alert('Size should be less than 1 mb')
                } 
           },
            error:function(error){console.log(error)},
            cancel:  function() {}
        });
```

This is giving me below error.

> maximum call stack size exceded.

Please tell how to resolve it.

Comment: Share your `GetBlobDataDropbox` code, please.

Comment: Code flow is not able to enter Dropbox.choose .It display error before that. 
When I printed Dropbox on console before Dropbox.choose then it contains values i.e. it is defined.

Comment: I'm afraid we couldn't help you more until you show us the rest of the code.

Comment: It feels like you put this code inside a *helper* instead of an *event*. Can you show the template code around your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the template code around my code. I am not using helper on this template.

```
 Template.AttachResume.events({
  'click #dropbox' : function(e){
     console.log('dropbox123  ',Dropbox)
    e.preventDefault();
    Dropbox.choose({
        linkType: "direct",
        multiselect: false,
        extensions: ['.doc', '.docx', '.pdf', '.rtf', '.txt', '.odt'],
        success: function(files) {
            console.log("files ", files[0]);
            if(files[0]['bytes']<1000000){
                GetBlobDataDropbox(files)   
            }else{
                alert('Size should be less than 1 mb')
            }   
        },
        error:function(error){console.log(error)},
        cancel:  function() {}
    });
  },
})
```